# Web page with all GCC error and warning messages?

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, diagnostics

I need a link to a webpage that
lists *all* the error messages and warnings
GCC can show; the actual messages, not descriptions.

It would be preferable if the list is
in the order of most frequently encountered
diagnostics.

Comment: i tried .po file also
it made no sense,
quite unusable. 
-handsomehermit

Comment: Did you found something new? Btw. for what do you need that? please send me an e-mail (noisy.pl@gmail.com), I think we can help each other

Comment: @noisy: You can mark this question as a [favorite](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585) to find out about new answers, or use the [feed](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/2968374) linked at the bottom right of the page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are going to find a page that describes **all** of them, but here's a page that has at least some of the most common: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_94.html

Answer (score 0):

> most frequently encountered diagnostics.

I am certain that "most frequently encountered" will vary depending on user.